# Why is "convert to graphics" not available? ArcGIS Pro layout editing

Tags: arcgis-pro, legend, layouts, graphics

I am creating a simple layout in ArcGIS Pro. I manually created a legend out of images and text, and put them together in a group layer. I want to convert the group layer to graphics so that I can resize it without having to resize each individual element. When I right-click and look for the "convert to graphics" option, it is grayed out and I cannot click on it. Furthermore, I cannot convert any element in my layout to graphics. Does anyone have any ideas why?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you already have a graphic. To accomplish what you want, you should select all the underlying components and Group them. This may be easiest to do from the Table of Contents. That will let you resize everything together.